# top.window.opener null in edge only, during oauth

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, oauth, oauth-2.0, microsoft-edge

So I am implementing oauth login and it works on every browser except microsoft edge. Chrome also has an unnoticeable error that might prove important.

I call:

```
window.open(facebookoauthurl)
```

from https://www.example.com/home/index This then opens a new tab. In this tab the user logins and is redirected back to https://www.example.com/externalauth/callback

The callback page is empty except for:

```
                try {
                top.window.opener.loginMethods.handleRedirect('@Html.Raw(Model.RedirectUrl)');
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
                top.window.opener.location = '@Html.Raw(Model.RedirectUrl)';
            }
            window.close();
```

This works in all browsers except edge where top.window.opener is not defined. If i extract this script into a function which is executed when you press a button google chrome shows an alert saying: "security error blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross origin frame" however once you dismiss the alert it executes the code anyway and the parent tab gets data passed to it!

I have read into the causes of this. The domains are exactly the same, I have even gone to setting document.domain on both pages to be exactly the same. It appears in various other examples that an issue can arise going through different zones in IE/edge but these are both in the same internet zone. It also works perfectly fine running on localhost in edge. The code will work if facebook and my site are in trusted sites.

There were multiple suggestions of using showModalDialog to achieve this but that is obviously now deprecated. I know this has to be possible somehow but I am absolutely stuck now.

It is just based upon: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1006013/OAuth-Social-Logins-Facebook-Google-Twitter-PayPal

Comment: Possible work arounds: Implement oauth flow in same browser tab (but I will lose my status changes on the page  I navigate away from!) or popup and parent communicate via 3rd party like signal r

Comment: In case anyone cares I ended up using the same tab and implemented state saving functionality for when the page reloaded with oauth authentication